# how to call method in custom directive controller method or function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When i click on a button, it should call `resetDropdown` function. The `resetDropdown` function is there in custom directive in that controller which when called alerts something.

My project used angular-dropdown plugin. extend functionalities form existing on as for my requirement. when i click on a button outside direcive. it should call to 'resetDropdown' mehtod.

Here is the code I have tried so far.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/7zL4ob5a/2/

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your overall goal here is, but your ng-click event on your button is set to resetMainFilters() which doesn't exists. At least not in the code you provided.

I believe you would want your ng-click set to resetDropdown().